# WebBluetooth API writeValueWithoutResponse does not seem to have an effect on connected device

Tags: javascript, bluetooth-lowenergy, web-bluetooth

I am trying to connect to a Buwizz V2 hub (and start a motor) via BLE on a windows machine via WebBluetooth in Google Chrome Browser. Tried it on Linux too, same results.

The API for the Buwizz is https://buwizz.com/BuWizz_2.0_API_1.3_web.pdf

The result of my code is

> ble.html:21 discoverDevicesOrDisconnect
> ble.html:31 discoverDevices
> ble.html:40 > Name: BuWizz
> ble.html:41 > Id: NtY+vKj4GR1vb/VowbQdJw==
> ble.html:42 > Connected: false
> ble.html:44 BluetoothDevice {id: 'NtY+vKj4GR1vb/VowbQdJw==', name: 'BuWizz', gatt: BluetoothRemoteGATTServer, ongattserverdisconnected: null, watchingAdvertisements: false, …}
> ble.html:74 connecting
> ble.html:77 Connected to NtY+vKj4GR1vb/VowbQdJw==
> ble.html:78 connected=true
> ble.html:96 discoverSvcsAndChars server=[object BluetoothRemoteGATTServer]
> ble.html:102 Got 1 services
> ble.html:109 Getting Characteristics for service 4e050000-74fb-4481-88b3-9919b1676e93
> ble.html:111 > Service: 4e050000-74fb-4481-88b3-9919b1676e93
> ble.html:117 >> Characteristic: 000092d1-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
> ble.html:125 FINISHED DISCOVERY
> ble.html:54 Try to startMotor
> ble.html:55 Will send command to Characteristic:000092d1-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
> ble.html:56 Characteristic has writeWithoutResponse ability:true
> ble.html:60 Motor command ->16,127,127,127,127,0
> ble.html:85 Try to set Powerlevel
> ble.html:86 Will send command to Characteristic:000092d1-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
> ble.html:87 Characteristic has writeWithoutResponse ability:true
> ble.html:97 Power command ->17,4

So I can discover and connect to the device, find the Service `4e050000-74fb-4481-88b3-9919b1676e93`, find the characteristic `000092d1-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb` and check that is has `writeWithoutResponse`.

Since the motor is not running after sending the command, I have obviously made something wrong.

And I guess that it is somewhere around here:

```
  console.log("Try to startMotor");
        console.log("Will send command to Characteristic:" + motor_characteristic.uuid);
        console.log("Characteristic has writeWithoutResponse ability:" + motor_characteristic.properties.writeWithoutResponse);

        let full_ahead_command_data = new Uint8Array;
        full_ahead_command_data =  Uint8Array.of(0x10, 0x7F, 0x7F, 0x7F, 0x7F, 0x00);
        console.log('Motor command ->' + full_ahead_command_data);

        motor_characteristic.writeValueWithoutResponse(full_ahead_command_data.buffer)
            .then(_ => { })
            .catch(error => {
                console.log('Error: ' + error);
                alert('Error: ' + error);
                return;
            });
```

I checked the hub and motor with the official app. Both are working fine, so i would appreciate hints where I made something wrong or made a wrong assumption.

Comment: Does the command succeed if you use writeValueWithResponse() instead? Does the command succeed if you use a different computer or operating system (like macOS or Android)?

Comment: Neither writeValueWithResponse nor writeValue (deprecated) work. I have not tried it on a different OS yet, but will try it on a linux machine as soon as I can.

Comment: Tried it on linux now, but it does not work either. Same results as windows. Does connect to the device, but the motor does not start running after the writeValueWithoutResponse command.

Comment: From the documentation it looks like you may need to first send a "set power level" command as the default on connection establishment is no power enabled.

Comment: @ReillyGrant You are right, power level needs to be set. I have a dedicated function for that, but neither setting powerlevel before or after the command for starting the motor helps.